# addToBackStack is not navigating back to the correct fragment

Tags: android, fragment-backstack, android-fragment-manager

hello im trying to include a backstack to EditProfile Fragment that when back is pressed it goes back to Profile Fragment but it goes back to the Home Fragment

> if you want more refrence of the code please tell me i will update the
> question with full code

**Profile Fragment**

```
editProfileButton = relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_button); // buuton to start editprofile fragment 
        editProfileButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Fragment edit_profile = new Edit_Profile();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, edit_profile);
            transaction.addToBackStack(String.valueOf(new Profile_Fragment())); // i thinked this method of implementing string.valueof will navigate back to the given fragment but as you know it is not working
            transaction.commit();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a good explanation in [this](https://medium.com/@bherbst/managing-the-fragment-back-stack-373e87e4ff62) blog post. You can try this code and also read more about it.

```
public void addSubscreen(Fragment fragment) {
    getSupportManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
    subscreensOnTheStack++;
}


public void popOffSubscreens() {
    while (subscreensOnTheStack > 0) {
        fragments.popBackStackImmediate();
    }
}
```